# How to select current date and future date in the calendar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select current date and future date in the calendar?
[image: Select current and future date]

I want to select June 6 and 7. When I run today below code works fine
But when I run tomorrow this script will fail because 6th June will be disabled. How to select current date and future date in the calendar

```java
List<WebElement>dates1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rc-calendar-date-value']"));
int dd=dates1.size();

for(int i=0; i<dd; i++)
{
    String date=dates1.get(i).getText();
    if(date.equalsIgnoreCase(“6”))
    {
        dates1.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<dd; i++)
{
    String date=dates1.get(i).getText();
    if(date.equalsIgnoreCase(“7”))
    {
        dates1.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Above code will fail when you run tomorrow.

Html:

```html
<div class="rc-calendar-body">
    <table class="rc-calendar-table" cellspacing="0" role="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <th role="columnheader" title="Sun" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">Su</span></th>
                <th role="columnheader" title="Mon" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">Mo</span></th>
                <th role="columnheader" title="Tue" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">Tu</span></th>
                <th role="columnheader" title="Wed" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">We</span></th>
                <th role="columnheader" title="Thu" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">Th</span></th>
                <th role="columnheader" title="Fri" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">Fr</span></th>
                <th role="columnheader" title="Sat" class="rc-calendar-column-header"><span class="rc-calendar-column-header-inner">Sa</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="rc-calendar-tbody">
            <tr role="row" class="">
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-5-26" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell-first-of-row rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">26</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-5-27" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">27</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-5-28" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">28</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-5-29" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">29</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-5-30" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">30</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-5-31" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">31</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-1" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-first-day-of-month-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell-last-of-row rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">1</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="rc-calendar-current-week rc-calendar-active-week">
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-2" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell-first-of-row rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">2</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-3" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">3</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-4" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">4</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-5" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-disabled-cell-last-of-row rc-calendar-disabled-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">5</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-6" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-today rc-calendar-first-selected-day rc-calendar-selected-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">6</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-7" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-in-range-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">7</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-8" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-selected-day rc-calendar-selected-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">8</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="">
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-9" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">9</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-10" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">10</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-11" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">11</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-12" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">12</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-13" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">13</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-14" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">14</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-15" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">15</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="">
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-16" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">16</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-17" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">17</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-18" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">18</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-19" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">19</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-20" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">20</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-21" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">21</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-22" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">22</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="">
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-23" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">23</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-24" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">24</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-25" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">25</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-26" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">26</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-27" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">27</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-28" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">28</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-29" class="rc-calendar-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">29</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="">
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-6-30" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-last-day-of-month-cell">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">30</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-7-1" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-next-month-btn-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">1</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-7-2" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-next-month-btn-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">2</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-7-3" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-next-month-btn-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">3</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-7-4" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-next-month-btn-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">4</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-7-5" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-next-month-btn-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">5</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td role="gridcell" title="2019-7-6" class="rc-calendar-cell rc-calendar-next-month-btn-day">
                    <div class="rc-calendar-date" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="rc-calendar-date-value">6</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please help out on this.

Comment: Please avoid attached snapshot.It is not going to help other contributor to help you out.Post html in a text format or if possible share page url.Thanks.

Comment: @KunduK Please check it:

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select multiple dates in the calendar, it would be a good idea to use a Page Object for Selenium:

```java
public class DatePickerPageObject {
    [FindsBy(how = How.CSS, Using = "table.rc-calendar-table")]
    private WebElement table;

    private SimpleDateFormat calendarDateFormat;

    public DatePicker(WebDriver driver) {
        calendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void chooseDate(Date dateToChoose) {
        String xpath = "./tbody/td[@title = '" + calendarDateFormat.format(date) + "']";
        WebElement dateCell = table.findElement(By.xpath(xpath);

        dateCell.click();
    }

    public void chooseTodayAndTomorrow() {
        Date today = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTime(today);
        calendar.add(1);
        Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();

        chooseDate(today);
        chooseDate(tomorrow);
    }
}
```

This at least hides the complexity of generating "today" and "tomorrow" as proper Date objects, and then selecting them in the calendar widget on the page.

Then using the date picker is trivial:

```java
DatePickerPageObject datePicker = new DatePickerPageObject(driver);

datePicker.chooseTodayAndTomorrow();
```

The nice thing about creating a class that is responsible for this behavior, besides hiding the complexity of interacting with a date picker, is the ability to add methods to this class later on that are capable of more complicated behavior, like selecting a larger range of dates, as an example:

```java
Date today = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTime(today);
calendar.add(7);
Date oneWeekFromToday= calendar.getTime();

datePicker.chooseRange(today, oneWeekFromToday);
```

(But I will leave this up to you to implement)

Comment: Thanks for your code. I ran the script with your code but its not working! Which ever day I run the script I want to select current date and future. Please help me out on this

Comment: @User2080: Do you mean "today" and "tomorrow"?

Comment: Are you able to select multiple days in the calendar at once?

Comment: Yes I can select multiple days in the calendar, check the screen shot above for more details.  I want to select current date and future date in the calendar. If I ran the script tomorrow I want to select 11 and 12 in the calendar. Please help me out on this

Comment: @User2080: I just rewrote my answer. Thanks for the clarification. I recommend a "page object" that encapsulates this behavior, since it is not trivial logic. I think you will have much better luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the Current date and pass the date instead of passing static values.
Just add current_date+1 and then run the code for future value.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
Date date1 = new Date(); 
String date2=formatter.format(date1);
date = new SimpleDateFormat("d").parse(date2);
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d",Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
```

In the above code you will get the current date. and then you can select the current date

```
for (int i=0; i<dd; i++) {
    String date=dates1.get(i).getText();
    if(date.equalsIgnoreCase(currentDate)) {
        dates1.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Now the code for future date will be

```
int FutureDate=currentDate+1;
for (int i=0; i<dd; i++) {
    String date=dates1.get(i).getText();
    if(date.equalsIgnoreCase(FutureDate)) {
        dates1.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, I tried another logic at last it worked!